# Java sound: what's the persistence of set controls?

Tags: java, controls, audio

Hiya - still @ the design stages of an app, and was wondering about the following with regards to Lines of type 'Port':

1. do the values entered last once the port is closed (it seems that port controls are only accessible if I open the port before asking for the port's controls)?
2. do the values entered impact only my applications access to the underlying hardware, or are the values entered system-wide ?
3. If system-wide do the values set remain once the app is terminated ?

... I *could* figure this out via mock-up / trial & error, however I figured I'm not the first person to wonder about this - any insight appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, given the experimentation it looks like if I set port-level controls the impact is @ the OS level, impacting all applications, and lasts beyond the application's operation.

Just a FYI for anyone else who's curious :-)